# Improve the performance of a sum (C version)

Tags: c, performance, loops, sum, intel

I am using a scientific calculation code. And I want to improve it a little bit if possible. I check the code with Amplifier. The most time consuming (heavily used) code is this:

```
double a = 0.0;
for(j = 0; j < n; j++) a += w[j]*fi[((index[j] + i)<<ldf) + k];
```

To me it is just a dot product of w and fi. I am wondering:

1. Does Intel compiler will do it automatically? (I mean treated the loop as the dot product of two vecterized array.)
2. Is there a way to improve the code? (I mean maybe define another array a1 the same size of w. Then all multiplied number can be stored in a1 (unrolled loop?). Do summation in the end. )
3. Other suggestions?

I am using parallel composer 2013 with visual studio. Any idea will be appreicated！:)

Comment: The biggest problem you have here is your reliance on gather-loads. If it's at all possible to re-order the data or change the algorithm in way such that the `fi[]` is sequentialized, then you'll be in much better shape. (potentially *many* times faster)

Comment: That aside, I don't see much room to optimize the code as is. The gather-load will be enough of a bottleneck to make other optimizations futile or insignificant.

Comment: @Mysticial Thanks. I got your idea. It is the gather-load! The data are scattered in the memory so that means each time the chunk of data which loaded cannot be fully used.

Comment: @Mysticial Do you think rewriting the loop by asm can improve it a lot? I know nothing about asm, and I am just curious.

Comment: I doubt it. And even if you knew what you were doing it, you probably won't get much out of it. A bottleneck is a bottleneck. It doesn't matter how fat you make the bottle, it won't flow any faster than the size of the neck.

Comment: @Mysticial OK. I get it. The way that data flow is fixed by the hardware (maybe how the memory is designed). Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could start by noticing that you always offset by a fixed amount `k` in your `fi` array...  I'm assuming it's of type `double*`.  So why not just offset by `k` once before you loop?

```
double *fik = fi + k;
```

In fact, you do the same with `i`.  The value `(index[j] + i) << ldf` is equivalent to `(index[j] << ldf) + (i << ldf)`.  So, you get:

```
double *fik = fi + k + (i << ldf);
double a = 0.0;
for(j = 0; j < n; j++) a += w[j] * fik[ index[j]<<ldf ];
```

Should be a little faster, unless the compiler has already decided to do that for you.

Comment: Thanks. Then I think I can save two adds. I'll try it tomorrow.

Comment: In terms of making the loop parallel, you need to consider the size of `n`.  If it is very large, then a parallel loop may be useful.  Otherwise the overhead involved won't be worthwhile.

Comment: Also, if you are using this loop multiple times without changing `ldf`, you may want to consider caching the value of `index[j]<<ldf`.

Comment: I've read that, say, adding the even terms in one variable, the odd terms in another, and then adding the two sums at the end can speed things up (at the risk of slightly changing the sum [though not necessarily for the worse]).  For this, you can increment `j` by 2 each time and do two additions each iteration.  The hope is that the processor can perform the computations simultaneously since they'll no longer depend on each other.  I don't know if that will really be effective here, though.

Comment: @paddy I tried this afternoon. It did improved it a little bit. And I learnt the pointer and array better. Overall, It improve maybe 1/200 of the performance. I agree that the code has to be parallel eventually. But I am now just optimize the serial code before I parallel it. Thanks.

Comment: @Joshua I don't understand you very well. But I think maybe you mean parallel (I saw you said simultaneously process the data)? If it is serial, I really have no idea of the benefit of separating the data by their odd even indices. Since the processor will run odd then run even. Can you explain more?

Comment: I got an answer from Intel. They told me that the SSE4.1 is actually improve such kind of loop. But still, it not very significant. Maybe I will just rearrange the data.

Comment: What I was suggesting is on page 103 of http://www.agner.org/optimize/optimizing_cpp.pdf.  I don't know if it will improve the performance in your program.

Comment: @JoshuaGreen Thanks again. That's a good resource. And I figured out your idea by reading it.

Comment: @JoshuaGreen But when I applied it， I don't have much benefit. So I think the speed of cpu process is not the main problem. Then I think it must be the gather-load issue. Since the data is scattered in the memory. When cache load the data, it cannot load a trunk of the data, since only some data in the trunk is useful.